# Rotate body according to touch movement box2d, cocos2dx

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-x-3.0

[image]
Hello, I have to create body rotation effect in box2d.Let me explain, I have a vehicle image which has 3 joints, i have made it using revolute joint, now when i drag any part of body then it should rotate according to user touch. See in the reference image where i have 3 joints, user will tap and drag body joint 3. now how to apply rotation according to user drag it. If i would do it using mousejoint then it will move whole vehical on user touch, i dont want to lift vehical i just want to rotate body according to user touch.. if u dont get question pl comment below i will try to explain it.. how would i do it!

snap of bodies i have created.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a weld joint between your vehicle and ground.